# Ошибка ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Исходный файл содержит 7066 строк x 66 столбцов вещественных чисел (без пропущенных значений). Пытаюсь нормализовать значения признаков следующим образом:

```
def normalize_feature(data, f_min=-1.0, f_max=1.0): 
    d_min, d_max = min(data), max(data) 
    factor = (f_max - f_min) / (d_max - d_min) 
    normalized = f_min + (data - d_min)*factor 
    return normalized, factor 
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = normalize_feature(df[c])
```

Раньше этот кусок кода меня не подводил, на таких же файлах работал на отлично, поэтому ошибка `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` ставит меня в тупик.

При том что:

```
In[35]: np.shape(df)
Out[35]: (7066, 66)
In[36]: len(df.index)
Out[36]: 7066 #казалось бы всё должно совпадать
```

Повторюсь, ни пропусков, ни NaN, ни прочих повреждений в исходных данных нет.

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7066 entries, 0 to 7065
Data columns (total 66 columns):
2.0         7066 non-null float64
3.0         7066 non-null float64
4.0         7066 non-null float64
5.0         7066 non-null float64
6.0         7066 non-null float64
7.0         7066 non-null float64
8.0         7066 non-null float64
10.0        7066 non-null float64
лаг         7066 non-null float64
11.0        7066 non-null float64
12.0        7066 non-null float64
13.0        7066 non-null float64
14.0        7066 non-null float64
15.0        7066 non-null float64
16.0        7066 non-null float64
17.0        7066 non-null float64
18.0        7066 non-null float64
19.0        7066 non-null float64
20.0        7066 non-null float64
21.0        7066 non-null float64
22.0        7066 non-null float64
23.0        7066 non-null float64
24.0        7066 non-null float64
25.0        7066 non-null float64
26.0        7066 non-null float64
27.0        7066 non-null float64
28.0        7066 non-null float64
29.0        7066 non-null float64
30.0        7066 non-null float64
31.0        7066 non-null float64
32.0        7066 non-null float64
33.0        7066 non-null float64
n           7066 non-null float64
Нефть       7066 non-null float64
Ребаланс    7066 non-null float64
USD         7066 non-null float64
Индекс      7066 non-null float64
34.0        7066 non-null float64
35.0        7066 non-null float64
36.0        7066 non-null float64
37.0        7066 non-null float64
38.0        7066 non-null float64
39.0        7066 non-null float64
40.0        7066 non-null float64
41.0        7066 non-null float64
42.0        7066 non-null float64
43.0        7066 non-null float64
44.0        7066 non-null float64
45.0        7066 non-null float64
46.0        7066 non-null float64
47.0        7066 non-null float64
48.0        7066 non-null float64
49.0        7066 non-null float64
50.0        7066 non-null float64
51.0        7066 non-null float64
52.0        7066 non-null float64
53.0        7066 non-null float64
54.0        7066 non-null float64
55.0        7066 non-null float64
56.0        7066 non-null float64
57.0        7066 non-null float64
58.0        7066 non-null float64
59.0        7066 non-null float64
60.0        7066 non-null float64
61.0        7066 non-null float64
t           7066 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(66)
memory usage: 3.6 MB
```

Сброс индекса `df.reset_index(drop=True)` и `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`, равно как и добавление столбца-индекса в исходный файл, ничего не меняет.

Импорт файла в IDE происходил и так:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

wb=xw.Book('...(условный путь)\\Исходный файл.xlsx')
data_excel = wb.sheets['Данные']
df = data_excel.range('A1:BN7067').options(pd.DataFrame, header = 1, index = False).value
```

и через `df = pd.read_excel(…)` и из формата .csv. Я не имею ни малейшего представления, что именно вызывает ошибку и как ее можно исправить.

Функция нормализации взята из книги:

> Бринк Хенрик, Ричардс Джозеф, Феверолф Марк  "Машинное обучение". -СПб.: Питер, 2017. -336 с.: ил. -(Серия «Библиотека программиста»). ISBN 978-5-496-02989-6

Возможно, в ней есть опечатка, которую я не замечаю.

Что не так и как исправить ошибку?

PS Python 3.7 - если это имеет значение

Comment: Приведите точный текст ошибки. и номер строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [готовым и быстрым решением](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

df_scaled = minmax_scale(df, feature_range=(-1, 1))
```

или так:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

mms = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
df_scaled = mms.fit_transform(df)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо